# .htaccess file not redirecting - guidance wanted

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have this url:

```
<a href="drive_to_london/?procid=12">details</a>
```

the url becomes in addressbar:

```
http://web228.sydney.webhoster.ag/soputnik/drive_to_london/?procid=12
```

but I want to process the logic in `details.php`.

How can I process the data in `details.php` in background and keep the first url in the address?

I tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^drive_to_(.*)$   http://web228.sydney.webhoster.ag/soputnik/details.php [R=301,L]
```

but it is not working, error is: **NOT FOUND**

please help

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the URL to change, then it's not a redirect, just a rewrite.

Change:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/drive_to_(.*)$   /test/details.php [R=301,L]
```

To something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/drive_to_(.*)$   /test/details.php?city=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is it possible the single slash after `http:` is causing it? The protocol should be `http://`

Comment: no, this is just my typo here in SOF. in my code, it is correct.

Comment: Oh, yeah. But that whole first bit is not really necessary anyway, let me edit.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test/drive_to_(.*?)/?$ /test/details.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Ok can you try this rule: `RewriteRule ^drive_to_(.*?)/?$ /test/details.php [R,L,NC]` for testing **or try my edited answer**.

Comment: look, i just created .htaccess in the folder where .php's live. and uploaded to server. this is fine,right?

Comment: That is usually fine but do you know what is DOCUMENT_ROOT of your website is and in what subdir you have `.php` files?

Answer (score 0):

1. dont forget to pass any url params to details.php.

   `Rewriterule ^/drive_for_(.*)/\?(.*)$ http://domain.de/test/details.php/?$1 [R=301,L]`
2. it seems relevant that you want to pass the city name as well, otherwise that context gets lost in the rewrite.  If that is another url param you could pass it through to details.php as such

   `Rewriterule ^/drive_for_(.*)/\?(.*)$  http://domain.de/test/details.php/?$2&city=$1 [R=301,L]`